# How can I negate a condition in a workflow?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

In Sharepoint Designer 2010, how can I negate a "If the file size is between x and y kilobytes" condition?

I need an action to be performed if the file is NOT in that file size interval.

So far I have an "Else-If" branch with my actions on the "Else". But I don't like to have an empty "Then".

How can I negate the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really hope there is better solution then using something like this:

[image]

Comment: You and me, both...

Comment: I believe that is going to be the only option without writing your own workflow activity.

Comment: And it works only for files under 953Gb :)

Comment: This sucks... but it will have to do...